# Some CodeNarc rules throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, ant, groovy, codenarc

So I'm using CodeNarc as an ant task in maven.

For my custom ruleset, I'm able to use IllegalRegexRule. However, when I try to add something else, I sometimes get a ClassNotFoundException.

For example, once I've added this to my ruleset.xml

```
<rule class='org.codenarc.rule.formatting.MissingBlankLineAfterPackage'>
    <property name='priority' value='1'/>
</rule>
```

I see

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (codenarc) on project myProject: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codenarc.rule.formatting.MissingBlankLineAfterPackage

Any idea why this would be happening? 
I'm using version 0.18 of codenarc, here's the ant dependency for CodeNarc:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codenarc</groupId>
    <artifactId>CodeNarc</artifactId>
    <version>0.18</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ant</groupId>
                <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Edit:
This problem still happens on version 0.21

Comment: So adding this same MissingBlackLineAfterPackage rule (available starting 0.21) still is not found when you run codenarc version 0.21 or is it a different rule that is not found?

Comment: It was happening in both versions. I forgot to add 'Rule' to the end of the rule name though.

Comment: ok. Be sure to mark your answer as the final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just making a typo. You need to use:

```
<rule class='org.codenarc.rule.formatting.MissingBlankLineAfterPackageRule'>
    <property name='priority' value='1'/>
</rule>
```

Notice the 'Rule' at the end of the class name.